# Tweepy: can´t print tweets in file

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I'm new to python (and programming in general)  and I'm trying to write a script to collect tweets. I can´t get the script to print the tweets in the file. The tweets appeared in Idle with the error "failed ondata, global name 'saveFile' is not defined" and they don't get printed in the file

i ran this code:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time

ckey = ???
csecret = ???
atoken = ????
asecret = "???

class listener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        print data
        savefile = open('twitDB.json','a')
        saveFile.write(data)
        savefile.write('\n')
        saveFile.close()
        return True
    except BaseException, e:
        print "failed ondata,",str(e)
        time.sleep(5)


def on_error(self, status):
    print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["movistar"])
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
```

Any kind of help is welcomed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **saveFile** variable.

First time you used it as save**f**ile, then you used save**F**ile (note the letter **f** and capital **F**)

Change all occurrences to the same name and it should work.

Also, be careful when doing that in the **on_data** method. As far as I know, it will be called for every single tweet you receive. That is, you will open the file, write the tweet, close the file and then again for each tweet.